# finOne() in mongoose fails with MongoServerError: Expected field collationto be of type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement a simple registration validation using express and MongoDb but the below line of code always fails with the below error

```
const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
```

The Error

```
_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:203
                callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document))
                         ^

MongoServerError: Expected field collationto be of type object
at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\NetRe_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:203:30)
at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\NetRe_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
at MessageStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
at processIncomingData (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\NetRe_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\NetRe_\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28) {


ok: 0,
code: 14,
codeName: 'TypeMismatch',
'$clusterTime': {
 clusterTime: Timestamp { low: 25, high: 1650230278, unsigned: true },
signature: {
  hash: Binary {
    sub_type: 0,
    buffer: Buffer(20) [Uint8Array] [
       74, 137, 251, 211, 139, 236,
       64,  99,  37,  21,  24, 232,
      160,  41,  22, 158,  46,  34,
       97, 169
    ],
    position: 20
  },
  keyId: Long { low: 2, high: 1641040568, unsigned: false }
}
},
operationTime: Timestamp { low: 25, high: 1650230278, unsigned: true },
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

The User Model structure

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

firstName: {type: String, required:true},
lastName: {type: String, required:true},
date: {type: Date},
id: {type: String, required:true, unique: true},
idType: {type: String, required:true},
gender: {type: String, required:true},
mobile: {type: String, required:true, unique: true},
email: {type: String, required:true},
password: {type: String, required:true, max: 1024, min: 6}
},
{ collation: 'user-data'})

const model = mongoose.model ('User', userSchema)

module.exports = model
```

Express server code

```
router.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{

//validate data before insert
const { error } = registerValidation(req.body);
if(error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)  
}

//Checking if the user is already int the database
const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
if(emailExist) {
    return res.status(400).send('Email already exists')
}

//Create new user
const user= new User(req.body);
try {

    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send(savedUser)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, it is looking for `collation` to be an object, you have it as a string. I am not sure what you are using the `user-data` string in the collation for. According to [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/collation/#:%7E:text=Collation%20allows%20users%20to%20specify,specific%20operations%20that%20support%20collation.):

> Collation allows users to specify language-specific rules for string comparison, such as rules for lettercase and accent marks.

So in order to use it, the `locale` field is mandatory. If you are sure you are wanting a collation on this schema, the simplest way would be to change your schema to this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, required:true},
  lastName: {type: String, required:true},
  date: {type: Date},
  id: {type: String, required:true, unique: true},
  idType: {type: String, required:true},
  gender: {type: String, required:true},
  mobile: {type: String, required:true, unique: true},
  email: {type: String, required:true},
  password: {type: String, required:true, max: 1024, min: 6}
},
{ collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 } })
```

Comment: thanks for your help I just removed the collation parameter and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with mongoose versions in different devices I solved this by replacing this $ below

```
"refreshes.$.refreshAt": SortType.DESC,
```

to 0

```
"refreshes.0.refreshAt": SortType.DESC,
```

I hope this will work for you .

Answer (score 0):

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String},
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, required: [true, "Email is required"],validate:validateEmail},
    role: { type: String, default: "user" },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
}, {
    collation: 'users'
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String},
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, required: [true, "Email is required"],validate:validateEmail},
    role: { type: String, default: "user" },
    status: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
}, {
    collaction: 'users'
})
```

"collection spelling mistake
you have to change collation to collection"